# How to place added elements to the DOM one per line

Tags: javascript

I have these fields.

[image]

When I click on button "Add", I wold like do add new inputbox under other.

**Code:**

```
var newWaypoint = document.createElement("INPUT");
newWaypoint.setAttribute("type", "text");
newWaypoint.setAttribute("class", "waypoints-field");
newWaypoint.setAttribute("id", "waypoint"+i);
document.getElementById("addressbox").appendChild(newWaypoint);
i++;
```

The first time it works fine, but after the next click result is:

[image]

How can I keep each input on a separate line?

Comment: just style the `input` to `display:block` in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
newWaypoint.style.display = 'block';
```

That way you add the style programmatically through the code, rather than coupling it with an external CSS file.

Comment: Thank you, it works.
Now I have another problem. I would like to add button to every added input.
example: [link](https://s23.postimg.org/b7s9mi5jv/2017_01_06_165338.png)

Comment: Well you'd just create a new button element and append it after the input. You might be better off using CSS for the styling if you want that particular look from the example.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :-

Append a new line before each textbox.

```
var newWaypoint = document.createElement("INPUT");
newWaypoint.setAttribute("type", "text");
newWaypoint.setAttribute("class", "waypoints-field");
newWaypoint.setAttribute("id", "waypoint"+i);
document.getElementById("addressbox").appendChild("br");
document.getElementById("addressbox").appendChild(newWaypoint);
i++;
```

Comment: That's not an optimal solution,